# Advanced array sorting/re-arranging in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have an array with the following theoretical values:

```
int[] elements = {A1, A2, B1, B2,
                  A3, A4, B3, B4,
                  C1, C2, D1, D2,
                  C3, C4, D3, D4};
```

Illustrative figure:

```
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | B | B |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | B | B |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | C | C | D | D |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | C | C | D | D |
                  + - + - + - + - +
```

Simply put I would like the array to be re-arranged to the following form:

```
int[] elements = {A1, A2, A3, A4,
                  B1, B2, B3, B4,
                  C1, C2, C3, C4,
                  D1, D2, D3, D4};
```

Illustrative figure:

```
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | A | A |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | B | B | B | B |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | C | C | C | C |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | D | D | D | D |
                  + - + - + - + - +
```

This particular example contains four sectors (A, B, C and D), but the algorithm I need should work however many or few sectors the array contains, and however many elements each sector contains.

The size of each sector is known (sector width and sector height) and also the amount of sectors (rows and columns). *All sectors are of the exact same size (width and height).* The amount of sectors has to be described as two values (rows ans columns) which is then multiplied to make up the actual sum of sectors. Eg. if 5 sectors are wanted, then 1 row and  5 columns could be specified.

Here follows an example of what a method preforming this sort could look like:

```
public int[] sectorSort(int[] elements,
                        int sectorWidth,
                        int sectorHeight,
                        int columns,
                        int rows);
```

Example of other sector setups:

```
                  Columns: 5
                  + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | B | B | C | C | D | D | E | E |
     Rows: 1      + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | B | B | C | C | D | D | E | E |
                  + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - + - +

                  Columns: 2
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | B | B |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | A | A | B | B |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | C | C | D | D |
     Rows: 3      + - + - + - + - +
                  | C | C | D | D |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | E | E | F | F |
                  + - + - + - + - +
                  | E | E | F | F |
                  + - + - + - + - +
```

I plan on using this to make an efficient sprite map class for a game engine I'm making. The elements in the array are ARGB color values, and the sectors are individual sprites. If the different sprites are arranged in the latter order then searching for individual sprites goes a lot faster and memory efficient.

Thank you!

EDIT1: Clarity.

EDIT2: Added more conditions and clarifications.

Comment: Are all sectors guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: Can you please add an example for 5 sectors, because I can not imagine how it looks for more than 4 sectors.

Comment: @Ralph: I can see how square numbers look in my mind (4, 9, 16), but I can't reliably imagine anything else...if it's 6, is it set up in a 3x2 or a 2x3 config?

Comment: Okay, I forgot some of the conditions. I'm adding them now. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to rearrange the existing array, or return a new array with arranged contents?

Comment: If you will be using this to retrieve single sprite data fast why not use a map instead of an array?

Comment: @Adriaan The array is the map. A map is a number of values with x and y coordinates. A map is just a construction around an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not going to get a better time complexity than this:
It creates a new array and copies each sector into it.

```
static T[] sectorSort<T>(T[] elements, int sectorWidth, int sectorHeight, int columns, int rows)
        {
            T[] sortedElements = new T[elements.Length];
            int n = 0;
            int arrWidth = sectorWidth * columns;
            for(int secY = 0; secY < rows; secY++)
                for (int secX = 0; secX < columns; secX++)
                {
                    int baseIndex = secY * arrWidth * sectorHeight + secX * sectorWidth;
                    for(int y = 0; y < sectorHeight; y++)
                        for (int x = 0; x < sectorWidth; x++)
                        {
                            int sourceIndex = baseIndex + y * arrWidth + x;
                            sortedElements[n++] = elements[sourceIndex];
                        }
                }
            return sortedElements;
        }
```

I can still see a lot of optimizations that can be done, however reading your question I see this is done in loading time so don't fuss too much about it.

EDIT: Fixed code

EDIT2: Test setup (C#)

```
    int[] array = new int[]
    {
        11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 51, 52, 53,
        14, 15, 16, 24, 25, 26, 54, 55, 56,
        17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 57, 58, 59,
        31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43, 61, 62, 63,
        34, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 64, 65, 66,
        37, 38, 39, 47, 48, 49, 67, 68, 69,
        71, 72, 73, 81, 82, 83, 91, 92, 93,
        74, 75, 76, 84, 85, 86, 94, 95, 96,
        77, 78, 79, 87, 88, 89, 97, 98, 99,
    };
    int[] sorted = sectorSort(array, 3, 3, 3, 3);
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            Console.Write(sorted[x + y * 9] + " | ");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the straight forward algorithm I was talking about :) +1 For writing it down!

Comment: You came a lot further than I did, but the algorithm is not giving me correct results.

Giving it

`[11, 12, 21, 22, 13, 14, 23, 24, 31, 32, 41, 42, 33, 34, 43, 44]`

makes it return

`[11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 13, 14, 31, 32, 23, 24, 41, 42]`  . The first two sectors are sorted correctly, but not the other two.

Comment: Well, it did for 2x2 sectors. I tried it on a 3x3 where each sector consisted of 3x3 values. It got like nothing right. I'll investigate your code. ;)

Comment: 3x3, with 3x3 sectors works fine for me. Are you setting the right values for sectorWidth, sectorHeight, columns, and rows? I'll add my test setup.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! Yeah! I forgot to change the other input parameters. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a straight forward algorithm iterating all sectors and all elements therein to rearrange them. This would be O(n*m), n=number of sectors and m = number of elements per sector. But you would have to rearrange the whole array. As an alternative (if memory is critical) you could create a sector based view of the original array this would take O(n) for creating the view and then O(m) to read the values of a single sector.

So reading all sectors would require O(n*m) in both cases. What improvement do you expect?

Comment: Let's say I want all values in sector D, then I would need to use an algorithm that goes through and finds the appropriate values in order and returns them. It's not an immensely difficult operation, but if it's going to be executed very frequently it would be a lot slower than if all the values in sector D were right after each other. You would just need to know where the first one is and how many values there are.

I tried your approach several times, but I could just not make it work. I'm in need of a more hands on example.